# Whether this proof regarding Bohr's second postulate is true or false?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, atomic-physics, frequency, atoms

Let us assume a particle oscillating with displacement $x$.

Now $x = A\sin(2πft)$

$$\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm dt} = v = 2πfA\cos(2πft)$$

Now $KE_\text{max}$ can be given when cosine value is 1; thus, 
$$KE_\text{max} = 2(π^2)(f^2)m(A^2) \tag{i}$$

Now let linear momentum be given as  $p =  2πmfA\cos(2πft)$ and let  $2πmfA = B$. 
Now $p/B = \cos(2πft)$ and $x/A = \sin(2πft)$

Now $\sin^2(2πft) + \cos^2(2πft) = 1$, thus

$$\frac{x^2}{A^2} + \frac{p^2}{B^2} = 1$$

Now the area of this ellipse is given as $πAB$ so,
$$∫p\mathop\!\mathrm dx = πAB$$

Now $E = nhf$ (Planck's Postulate), thus from (i)

$$2(π^2)(f^2)m(A^2) = nhf \tag{ii}$$

Using (ii), we have

$$∫p\mathop\!\mathrm dx = nh$$

But we want to find angular momentum not linear so we put limits of integral from 0 to 2π and assign a new variable for angular momentum as $L$ and $\mathrm dx = \mathrm dθ$

thus we have $L = nh/2π$ (Bohr's Second Postulate)

Hence proved.

Comment: Well, first off, your system doesn't even have any angular momentum at all, it's a 1D oscillation. You can't just rename $x$ to $\theta$ and $p$ to $L$.

Comment: @knzhou Its not about rename, I have just turn around the dx strip which I used to find area from 0 to 2pi in which theta is variable not x and thus it gaved me these conclusions

Comment: If you can prove a postulate then it isn't a postulate, it a consequence...

Comment: @DJohnM yeah john

Comment: @knzhou is correct. You have indeed attempted to rename variables, in an utterly incorrect fashion. This "proof" is nothing more than a series of disjoint algebraic manipulations held together by "well, this here looks superficially like that over there" with nothing of actual substance to hold them together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "proof" is not correct because it is not a proof. All you've done is provide a layer of algebraic manipulations that is thick enough for the reader (meaning you yourself) to miss where the postulate was asserted.

In your case, you've introduced "Planck's postulate" that $E=nhf$ without any argumentation for its validity in the situation where you're using it. This leaves a gaping logical hole in your proof that renders it useless.

(Similarly, your substitutions $p\to L$, $\mathrm dx\to \mathrm d\theta$ are completely unjustified and ultimately incorrect, so they would also be enough to sink your proof. But your proof is already sunk by that point.)

Bohr's second postulate is called a postulate for a reason. There are no known ways to derive it from postulates which are more fundamental and where the derivation does not irrevocably change some aspect of the hypotheses in ways that are too transformative for the manipulation to be termed an implication.

Comment: And yeah I would probably prove uncertainty and de broglie wavelength to give you the justification for planck postulate.

Comment: And yeah sir, it was a nice argument regarding this proof but yeah I have the verification of de broglie wavelength which might make this proof okay to you

Comment: And yeah I need your guidance regarding this

Comment: And yeah sorry if I sound bad but I meant it

Comment: Please guide me further if you see any misunderstandings in me. I would probably happy because I like to learn things because being in high school makes me in bunch of incomplete knowledge.